# GoogleApps Datastore Cons and Pros

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I've been reading more about Google AppEngine and learned python in the past couple of weeks, including working with MongoDB. What I need the most is a scalable database solution. Before discovering Google AppEngine, the only three DB solutions I find useful are DynamoDB, MongoDb and BigCouch.

I find out how that I really like python language, and for one coming from ASP.NET development, I've decided to switch and develop my app using python. My first choice was to develop my application using python + bottle + mongoDB.  The problem is that DynamoDB is very expensive, and the lack of easy to use backup/restore options made me pass Amazon's offering.

Google AppEngine datastore is much more affordable. However, I still can't find information regarding some specific question on Google's website

Here are some of the questions I need answer to:

- Does Google Datastore support backup/restore within the administration console?
- If I want to backup/restore 50TB of data, how much time it takes to backup/restore the data? Where it is stored? what are the costs?
- How much time it takes to backup 1TB of data for example?
- Does DataStore support caching in the database layer
- Any cons that I should be aware of?

Those some of the question that I need to get answers to. MongoDB is an excellent product and developing web app using Mongo + Python + bottle is fun fun fun. However, I prefer a full DB hosted solution like one offered by Google. But before I do that, I need to be sure that I'm not missing anything.

Comment: If you use NDB the datastore will apply a level of caching automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here are some of the questions I need answer to:
>
> Does Google Datastore support backup/restore within the administration
>   console?

<strike>No.</strike> Yes. You can back up and restore data from within the Administration Console by enabling datastore_admin for an application (Thanks to Idan Shechter for pointing this out!) More info can be found here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin

You can also download the data through the command line. See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata

> If I want to backup/restore 50TB of data, how much time it takes to backup/restore the data?

It depends on where you back the data up to. Backing up to the Blobstore or Google Cloud storage will probably take much less time than backing up to your local machine. Transferring 50TBs to your local machine will take a long time and depend on many factors including network speed.

> Where it is stored?

If you use the Datastore Administration, you can backup to the Blobstore or to Google Cloud Storage. If you use the command line tools, it will be stored where you choose to download the data to.

> what are the costs?

The Blobstore costs $0.13/GB/Month and gives you 5GB free. Google Cloud Storage is $0.12 per GB/Month up to the first TB. You can see more pricing info for Cloud Storage here:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/pricingandterms

Bandwidth costs are $0.12 per GB (The first GB is free). More details on pricing can be seen here:
https://cloud.google.com/pricing/

> How much time it takes to backup 1TB of data for example?

Again, it depends on where you back up to and your transfer speeds.

> Does DataStore support caching in the database layer Any cons that I should be aware of?

No, it does not support database layer caching.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, there is an experimental option to backup/restore data which I found very useful. And you can backup the data on remote location on Google infrastructure: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the answer to include the Datastore Admin information.

Comment: Thanks. I am really looking into their solution. NoSQL with terabytes of data storage capability with backup and restore, no one offers such a thing, no one.